# Replacing a word with another word in MS Word using c#

Tags: c#, regex, ms-word

I want to replace a date (26:12:2012) in my document with a word "date".  I am using c# and doing a customization of MS Word.

Comment: Please read the help center article on [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Post some code - what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Regex.Replace(source, "\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{4}", "Date");
```

Comment: What is source here? MS Word location?

Comment: The content of your document.